# pub_date is invalid in Django tutorial error

Tags: python, django, web-applications, web-application-design

```
C:\mysite>python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2012, 23:31:26) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from polls.models import Poll,Choice
>>> Poll.objects.all()
[]
>>> import django
>>> from django.utils import timezone
>>> p= Poll(question="what's new?",pub_date= timezone.now())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 367, in __init__
    raise TypeError("'%s'is an invalid keyword argument for
                          this function"%kwargs.keys()   [0])
TypeError: 'pub_date' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your Poll class? Does it have field `pub_date`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but I had this problem too and I found the answer. Change yor models.py file to:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your models.py probably you mistyped the pub_date Datetime field

Comment: ya i got it... but i have set it but new one error is arised here